# Openstack: Are components related to a keystone::project auto garbage-collected upon project deletion?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, openstack-keystone

Hello dear community,

in the research of how to properly delete projects and their resources via the OpenStack API  I was only able to find a hint in the official python sdk, the [project_purge.py](https://github.com/openstack/python-openstackclient/blob/master/openstackclient/common/project_purge.py#L84) ([docs](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/pike/cli/command-objects/project-purge.html)). Here deletion is handled for "servers, images, volumes, snapshots, backups", but not for [networks](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/network/v2/?expanded=show-port-details-detail,show-network-details-detail#networks), subnetworks, floating_ip, ports,  which are linked to projects and have dependencies to each other the more or less.

Following that, are stale resources garbage collected after time if they are not bound to a project, user , etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not. You need to remove every component manually, and in the correct order (a network can't be removed as long as the attached subnet exists etc.).

Comment: Thanks a lot Gerald, I learned the same from some consultants now. I will wait if some more answers pop up and then accept your response it that is ok?